# Android Device Policy migration

Tags: android-management-api

DPC migration is available from Android P, i.e. a device can be re-enrolled to a new EMM without factory reset it.

My question is: does the Android Device Policy support this feature? If so, does it support it in both ways, i.e. migrating from or to the Android Management API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Management API doesn't support DPC migration at the moment.

We don't have any timeline to share about when it will be supported as we are still evaluating the use cases and requirements.

One use case is to allow migrating from custom DPC to the Android Management API, but the feedback we received so far is that it's simpler to support both DPCs for a while as devices are refreshed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred. If I understand correctly, as of today, a customer with devices enrolled with EMM X cannot migrate to AMAPI without factory reset the whole fleet. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, a device enrolled with a custom DPC needs to be factory reset in order to be managed with the Android Management API. But you could consider migrating a customer gradually, by enrolling new devices with the Android Management API while waiting for old devices to be refreshed.